# Create Condition for Connectors of Datapoints R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, igraph

This is my Initial Data

```
library(igraph)
From <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
To <- c("NULL",1,2,3,2,"NULL",6,7)
Value<-c(4,2,2,7,1,2,7,2)
Data <- data.frame(From,To,Value)
Network <- graph.data.frame(Data[,c("From","To")],directed=TRUE)
Network<- Network - "NULL"
plot(Network)
```

I want to create a condition which adds a characterization of the Datapoints.
So far i was capable of creating, the first and 2nd Degree of Condition, but i'm not capable of finding an Solution on how to create the 3rd condition to finalize the whole Construct.
I was capable of creating the Condition for the Root and the Starter, my Problem is how could i construct the condition for the connectors of the Starters. In this case the Connectors should be number 2 and 3. And Finally who didn't got characterized should be called Follower.

- Root: Writes to no NULL
- Starter: Value>X
- Connector: Connects the starters(There will always be only one way of connecting them)
- Follower= Rest

Some code here

```
cond<-Data$To=="NULL"
ToP<-ifelse(cond,"Root","Follower")
cond<-Data$Value>3
ToP<- ifelse(cond,"Starter",ToP)
NewData<-cbind(Data,ToP)
View(NewData)
```

My FinalData should kinda look like this:

```
From <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
To <- c("NULL",1,2,3,2,"NULL",6,7)
Value<-c(4,2,2,7,1,2,7,2)
ToP<-c(Starter,Connector,Connector,Starter,Follower,Root,Starter,Follower)
Data <- data.frame(From,To,Value, ToP)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you trying to conditionally add edges between nodes to your graph?

Comment: I'm trying to characterize every Point in a Graph, and i'm missing the last Condition, which should call the inbetweeners between the starters as Connectors.

Comment: @Carlo based on your desired data, i've added an image with the labeling you've described. What makes "6" a root? So 1 would have also been a root had it not had value>3?

Comment: @MrFlick The Idea comes from a Discussion Forum and the Root start a new Topic, The Starters are the ones which make Threat interesting and a lot of people start to reply to them, actually the Value should be the Indegree, but for having a better example i thought it would be better to create a Value. So that means that Starters can be Root's but they don't have to. And for my purpose it isn't so Important to know if they would also be Root's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still a bit messier than I would like, bit this appears to assing the correct lables to the vertices

```
V(Network)$ToP <- ifelse(Data$To=="NULL","Root","Follower")
V(Network)$ToP[Data$Value>3] <- "Starter"

vs <- V(Network)[ToP=="Starter"]
sp <- shortest.paths(Network, vs,vs)
cx <- which(is.finite(sp) & lower.tri(sp), arr.ind=T)

for(i in nrow(cx)) {
   pp <- get.shortest.paths(Network, c(vs)[cx[i,1]], c(vs)[cx[i,2]])
   fidx <- tail(head(pp$vpath[[1]], -1), -1)
   if(length(fidx)>0) {
       V(Network)[fidx]$ToP<-"Connector"
   }
}

#verify with plot
V(Network)$color <- as.numeric(factor(V(Network)$ToP))+1
plot(Network)
legend(.5, -.5, levels(factor(V(Network)$ToP)), col=2:5, pch=20)
```